# How to ensure that solution will be delivered in time in accordance with the estimates?

Tags: development-process, estimation

Very often developers are asked to provide estimates (at least rough ones) when a solution or feature will be ready.
What steps development team should take to ensure that estimated solution will be delivered in time in accordance with provided estimates?

Comment: Finish writing the code before giving the estimate.

Comment: When committing to a delivery date tell them the month, but not the year. It gives you some flexibility. :)

Comment: Rank the tasks in order of risk, and perform the riskiest tasks first.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There are two thing you can do to finish a project faster and one to make it more likely to finish before the estimated date.

To make a project go faster.

1. Remove features. With less work to do the work will be completed sooner.
2. Hire more programmers. With more people to do the work, the work will be completed sooner

To make it more likely to finish before the estimated date

1. Increase the estimate to at least double your first estimate.

Unfortunately there is a million things you can do that will make a project go slower and be late.

Comment: “*Hire more programmers*”. This is pretty much guaranteed to delay the project; not assist it is being finished by some arbitrary date called “on time”. Nine women can’t make a baby in one month and all that...

Comment: they can through the magical wonder of pair programming!!

Comment: The, adding more people slows things down argument is a bit flimsy in my view. Sure it _can_ slow things down, but experienced developers are able to jump right in and start completing tasks

Comment: Adding more people speeds things up if their work is entirely independent of each other, and all the new people are fully "seasoned" (experienced and knowledgeable). Otherwise, it may speed things up, but more likely, slow them down.

Comment: @FrankHileman I think it would be more accurate to say that there is an 'onboarding cost' and an upper limit depending on project size. Generally more people = faster

Comment: "Hire more programmers". I agree with other comments here that it will likely delay the project. Onboaring new people, even experienced takes time. Learning about a new organization takes time. Learing about existing process takes time. Learing about the existing code base takes time. However when you add more people the biggest problem is the communication overhead that increases with every added programmer.

Comment: @OskarSjöberg et all, so you are saying that if I have a 5 year project to write Windows 12 hiring more than one programmer is unneeded?

Comment: @Ewan "Generally more people = faster": That depends largely on how far along you are with the project. If you are in the last month of a 5 year project and you still have several months of work left, then no amount of additional people will save you. If you find early on that you need more people, then it is realistic that more people will increase the speed (sufficiently).

Answer (score 6):

This question highlights a common problem with estimates, in any field. An estimate is a guess. It has a chance of being wrong. Therefore to talk of “delivering on time” when estimates are involved is a nonsense. To deliver on time, one must offer a guarantee; not an estimate.

So one solution is to turn that estimate into a guarantee. A good approach (for the developer at least) is to multiply that estimate by a figure between 3-10, depending on how many likely risks there are. That becomes your guaranteed figure.

A far better approach is to adopt an iterative approach to development. If you are only estimating what can be achieved in the next 2-3 weeks, then the risks of significant slippage of actual versus estimates is reduced. Of course, there is then no estimate at all of the final end date, but since most software products are never finished, as new releases are made all the time, that’s a cultural issue that can be addressed through education of other parts of the business.